# tomcat Context Element

Tags: ajax, rest, tomcat

I have a strange effect defining a tomcat context element.
With development i used META-INF/context.xml. On deployment it's
$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/engine/myfooservice.xml

Is a plain simple context def - path and datasource:

```
<Resource
  name="dataSourceName"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  password="s3cr3t"
  driverName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
  maxIdle="32"
  maxWaitMillis="5000"
  username="stupidLooser"
  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@HHHHHHH:1521:XXX"
  maxTotal="64"/>
```

Using META-INF it work's as expected. Using $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/engine/myapp.xml there is 
a different behaviour with URLs.

Some 'App' calls a rest Service (myfooservice) to display some information *before* realm login on the login screen.
App  ---AJAX----> myfooservice on same Tomcat (/App /myfooservice).

Using $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/engine/myapp.xml the url on login is changed to 
 http://$host:$port/APPContext/index/$myfooserviceCONTEXT/RestURL which is pretty wrong - non existent (all browsers).
Breaks login.

Using META-INF/context.xml the login work's as expected. j_security is called and the final
URL is  http://$host:$port/APPContext/index  (all Browsers) as expected.

I have no idea why $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/engine/myfooservice.xml behaves differently. From the docs i would
conclude that there is no difference.

Comment: opps - its tomcat 8. Linux and Windows ..

Comment: Is the engine literally named 'engine'? Not Catalina by any chance?

Comment: Catalina/localhost/ ....

Answer (score 0):

Property Naminng error - opps. The Context was also defined in META-INF/context.xml - correct - with driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver".

The conf/... entry has priority over META-INF/context.xml. Seems i got a mix (Datasource worked) and a strange side effect as result (path problem).